# When does probability mass outside a sufficiently large ball is small?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Many times when I read books about statistics or probability theory, I encounter proofs which said:

> For any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $\text{Pr}\{X\in S_M\}>1-\epsilon$

(The $S_M$ is the ball centered at origin with radius $M$)

But is this always true for **any** types of distribution of $X$, or am I just missing some important condition which the proof implicitly assumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ a random variable. Let $S_n=\{\omega\in\Omega : |X(\omega)|<n\}$. Then $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ and $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n = \Omega, $$
so $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(S_n)=\mathbb P(\Omega) = 1. $$
$\mathbb P(S_n)$ is an increasing sequence, as $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ implies $\mathbb P(S_n)\leqslant \mathbb P(S_{n+1})$. So given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M$ such that $n\geqslant M$ implies $\mathbb P(S_n)>1-\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$, i.e. if $X$ takes values in $\mathbb R$, then the statement is always true.

We have $\{X\in\mathbb R\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{|X|<n\}$ where $\{|X|<1\}\subseteq\{|X|<2\}\subseteq\cdots$.

Based on that it can be shown that $P(\{|X|<n\})$ converges to $P(\{X\in\mathbb R\})=1$.

---

Edit:

For a proof of that see the answer of @Math1000 (he was a bit faster).

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer since you posted it first :)

Comment: @Math1000 Couldn't resist to "pay back":).